# Are ∈ and ℝ symbols available in eqn/roff?

Tags: unicode, special-characters, groff, roff

A set of commonly used symbols to represent that a variable belongs to a given real coordinate space are ∈ ("ELEMENT OF", Unicode U+2208) and ℝ ("DOUBLE-STRUCK CAPITAL R", Unicode U+211D).

Are those two symbols available in `eqn`, `troff`, and/or `groff`? I can not find them in the documentation.

*Edit:*

I have tested provided answer and I can get symbol ∈ ("ELEMENT OF", Unicode U+2208), but not symbol ℝ ("DOUBLE-STRUCK CAPITAL R", Unicode U+211D).

Specifically, if I do:

```
.TL 
Test

.NH
Introduction

.LP
Given an input in subspace \[u211D]:
.EQ
x \[mo] \[u211D] sup 2
.EN
with output estimated value:
.EQ
y hat
.EN
```

I get the following error:

```
cat test.ms | eqn | groff -ms > test.ps
troff: <standard input>:8: warning: can't find special character 'u211D'
```

As it can be seen in the PS output ∈ is shown, but ℝ is not:

[image: groff output]

I am using `FreeBSD 12` `eqn` and `groff`.

Comment: For a full list of "Blackboard Bold" with superior LaTeX versions versus Unicode versions, see
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blackboard_bold#Usage

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to see a unicode character like U+211D in groff you need to find a font that contains it, and provide the font metrics file for it to groff, usually by converting a ttf file to pfa and adding it to a list.

One site that does the look-up for you for some common fonts is [fileformat.info](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/211d/fontsupport.htm) which shows most of the `DejaVu` fonts contain this character, eg `DejaVu Serif`. On Fedora this ttf font can be installed from a package `dejavu-sans-fonts`, and so I presume FreeBSD might have something similar. (If not, try one of the other matched fonts).

Alternatively, if you have the `fc-match` command you can find font files you already have with the character:

```bsh
fc-match -s -f '%{file}\n' ':charset=211D'
```

You need to pick out the TrueType files (usual suffix `.ttf`) from this list.

Alternatively, if you have the `fc-list` and `ttx` commands you can do a slow search through the ttf fonts for the character name with:

```bsh
fc-list | 
sed -n 's/\.ttf: .*/.ttf/p' |
xargs -l -t ttx -t cmap -o - 2>&1 |
grep  'ttx\|DOUBLE-STRUCK CAPITAL R'
```

If it finds the glyph it will output the filename and the match, eg:

```
ttx -t cmap -o - /usr/share/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSansMono.ttf 
      <map code="0x211d" name="uni211D"/><!-- DOUBLE-STRUCK CAPITAL R -->
```

You can then read Peter Schaffter's [explanation](https://www.schaffter.ca/mom/momdoc/appendices.html) about *Adding fonts to groff*. Though this is written for the `mom` macros, it applies to groff in general, though your macros may not handle a *family* automatically.  He conveniently provides a [shell script](https://www.schaffter.ca/mom/bin/install-font.sh) to do the work for you. Some tweaking may be needed as every distribution likes to place files in different places.

You can then add the following to your `eqnrc`, for example:

```
define @R '"\f[DejaVuR]\[u211D]\fR"'
```

The following doesn't need any new fonts:

```
define in '{type "relation" size +3 \[mo]}'
```

Comment: Thanks meuh for such comprehensive explanation. This is for sure a good reference on how to allow groff incorporating unicode characters. For this particular case I suspect that from a practical point of view, it might be easier and wiser to just use `\[mo]` as suggested by Gilles above and use a bold or italic R as an alternative notation as suggested here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4129214/can-%e2%84%9c-be-used-instead-of-%e2%84%9d-to-represent-a-real-coordinate-space.

Answer (score 7):

The set of named glyphs is documented in the [`groff_char` man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/groff_char.7.html). I see `\[mo]` for ∈, but no ℝ.

You can input arbitrary characters with `[uNNNN]` where `NNNN` are hexadecimal digits, so `\[u211D]` for ℝ. You can also use UTF-8 input, i.e. insert ℝ directly. You can define a name for it with the [`.char` request](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/groff.7.html#Requests):

```
.char \[Real] \[u211D]
```

My answer solely covers how you input the characters. I don't know whether the fonts that Groff uses cover these characters or how to teach it to use alternative fonts if they don't.

Comment: Thanks. I have tested it but still can not get ℝ. See edited original question.

Comment: @M.E. Sorry, I don't know how to teach Groff how to find a character in a font. For ℝ you may be able to approximate with `| \negativespace R` (depending on the font), but I don't even know how to do a negative horizontal space in roff.

Answer (score 2):

For completeness, here is how you can create an overstruck R in basic troff/groff, and also in `eqn`.

You can use the `\h` troff command to do a local horizontal movement backwards of `0.83m`, which is a fraction of the width of an *em*. An *em* is a typesetting conventional unit that is about the width of the `m` character in a font. So we can have an R overstruck with another R:

```troff
The R\h'-.83m'R space 1.
```

To make this more readable, you can define a string (`.ds`) called `myreal` with this sequence and instantiate it with `\*[myreal]`:

```
.ds myreal R\h'-.83m'R
The \*[myreal] space 2.
```

In `eqn`, you can do horizontal movement with `back 50` to move left 50/100ths of an *em*, so we need `R back 50 R`, but you also want to use the Roman font, so it would be best to define a macro `myreal`:

```
.EQ
define myreal 'roman { R back 50 R }'
delim $$
.EN
```

and then use it. By also defining inline delimiters of `$` and `$` (start and end) you can call the macro in the text, as well as in an equation:

```
Given an input in subspace $myreal$:
.EQ
x \[mo] myreal sup 2
.EN
```

[image]

---

But after all that, I found that eqn has provided the `fat` command to overstrike with offset. Depending on the font size you may need to play with the `fat_offset` parameter (which is units of ems/100). For my example above, you can therefore also use

```
.EQ
set fat_offset 15
x \[mo] fat roman R sup 2
.EN
```

Comment: That's a brilliant solution

Comment: I added a slightly better alternative using the eqn fat command.